# Can't start a thread (implementing Runnable)

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to understand why my FreeThread doesn't start a thread.
Well, I can see that threads corresponding to HotThreads appear in the debugger.

But when I add a FreeThread, no thread appears. If I try to trace it step by step, the cursor doesn't go to the superclass overridden run(), but goes to the `start()` method of Thread class.

How can I start FreeThreads?

```
public class HotThread implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {}
}

public class FreeThread extends HotThread {
   public FreeThread(int timeout) {
        super();
        ...  
    }
}

public class ThreadPool {
     public ThreadPool(int numberOfHotThreads) {
         for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHotThreads; i++) {
            HotThread ht;
            Thread t;
                ht = new HotThread(); // Нагруженный поток (есть задача).
                t = new Thread(ht);
                t.start();
         }
     }

    public void addFreeThread() {
        FreeThread ft = new FreeThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(ft);        
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `run()` method really empty?  If so then the threads are most likely starting and immediately finishing and you never see them in the debugger because they've already completed.

Comment: No, not empty. There is Thread.currentThread().start(); there.

Comment: You won't see the debugger step through to `run` because it gets called on the new thread. If you insert a breakpoint *in* `run` you should see it gets called.

Comment: @Trts how do you suppose a started thread starts itself again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> public void run() {}
> ```

So if your `run()` method really empty, then the thread is starting but immediately finishing and you never see them in the debugger because they've already completed.   Try putting a `Thread.sleep(10000000);` so you can see the thread running.  Or as @Radiodef commented, you could put a breakpoint there in the debugger and it should stop there.

> No, not empty. There is Thread.currentThread().start(); there.

This is wrong.  If you enter the `run()` method then the thread is already starting.  By trying to `start()` it again, you will cause an `IllegalThreadStateException` to be thrown because of an incorrect thread state which will kill the running thread immediately.  The idea that you can ever `start()` the current (running) thread is an invalid concept by definition.